# Irreducible representations of $SO(p,q)$

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, lie-groups

Let $n=p+q$. Let $SO(p,q)$ be the real matrix group containing $n\times n$ real matrices preserving the diagonal matrix $diag(1,\ldots, 1, -1, \ldots, -1)$ of signature $(p,q)$. The inclusion $SO(p,q)\subset GL(\mathbb R^n)\subset GL(\mathbb C^n)$ gives a natural $n$-dimensional complex representation $V$ of $SO(p,q)$.

How do we describe the irreducible decomposition of $V\otimes V$ as $SO(p,q)$-modules?

For example, when $p=n\neq 2,4$ and $q=0$, the irreducible representation of $V\otimes V$ is given by
$$Sym^2V^0\oplus \mathbb C\oplus \mathfrak{so}(n,\mathbb C),$$
where $Sym^2V^0$ signifies the harmonic part of $Sym^2V$ and $\mathbb C\cong Sym^2V/Sym^2V^0$.
This is done by analysing the irreducible sub-representations of $\mathfrak{so}(n,\mathbb C)$ on $V\otimes V$ and discuss if they induce representations for $SO(p,q)$.

Can similar methods applied to find irreducible decompositions of $SO(p,q)$?